# On delete cascade in one table

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

My module is about user permissions.

An user can own a device. An user can give permissions for this device to another user. There are no read/write permissions: if you have permissions you can do the same as everyone other with permissions => *children* can give permissions to.

```
permission inheritance: 
A gives B permission. B gives C permission. C gives D permission.

a --> b --> c --> d

table: USER_DEVICE
 ---------------------------------
| FK_USER | FK_DEVICE | FK_PARENT |
|---------|-----------|-----------|
| a       | d         | null      |
| b       | d         | a         |
| c       | d         | b         |
| d       | d         | c         |
 ---------------------------------
```

When user `a` removes the permission for device `d` on user `b` every children should be deleted recursive.

```
DELETE USER_DEVICE WHERE FK_DEVICE = 'd' AND FK_USER = 'b'
```

should trigger

```
DELETE USER_DEVICE WHERE FK_DEVICE = 'd' AND FK_PARENT = 'b'
```

should trigger

```
DELETE USER_DEVICE WHERE FK_DEVICE = 'd' AND FK_PARENT = 'c'
```

Is it possible to create this behavior as a delete cascade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: A foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` works just fine. See joops answer for details.

An `ON DELETE CASCADE` works for foreign keys, but not for these kinds of constraints. Instead, you could create an `AFTER DELETE` [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) for your table which deletes the dependent rows.

Comment: It should work just fine for a reflexive FK reference. You just need a `FOREIGN KEY (FK_DEVICE, FK_PARENT) REFERENCES thesametable(FK_DEVICE, FK_USER) ON DELETE CASCADE`. A trigger, by contrast, will be prone to difficult race conditions or (if you use locking to work around the races) deadlocks. Maybe delete the answer?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I can't delete my answer because it's accepted. So I just added a comment to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Works here:

```
CREATE table user_device(
         fk_user varchar NOT NULL
        , fk_device varchar NOT NULL
        , fk_parent varchar
        , PRIMARY KEY(fk_user,fk_device)
        , FOREIGN KEY(fk_parent,fk_device) REFERENCES user_device (fk_user,fk_device) ON DELETE CASCADE
        );

INSERT INTO user_device(fk_user,fk_device,fk_parent) VALUES
 ('a' , 'd' , null )
,('b' , 'd' , 'a' )
,('c' , 'd' , 'b' )
,('d' , 'd' , 'c' )
        ;

SELECT * FROM user_device ;

DELETE FROM user_device WHERE fk_user = 'a';

SELECT * FROM user_device ;
```

---

RESULT:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 fk_user | fk_device | fk_parent 
---------+-----------+-----------
 a       | d         | 
 b       | d         | a
 c       | d         | b
 d       | d         | c
(4 rows)

DELETE 1
 fk_user | fk_device | fk_parent 
---------+-----------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Right, this should work fine. I must have been confused when writing my answer (although a trigger can work too, of course). Should I edit my answer, or is this a problem, because it's already accepted with a different content?

Comment: I don't mind. Maybe in the future you take a bit more time before accepting; the answers to SQL-questions come reasonable slow, and the people answering them could be anywhere on the planet. (so: at least 24 hours ?) BTW: there *is* a data modelling problem here: the relation device-> owner is not expressed uniquely in this table, and should be expressed in another table.

Comment: @KarlBartel NB: sorry, I thought you were the OP